# Localizable xcassets files?

Tags: image, localization, xcode5

In previous versions of xcode you could set image files as localizable files and import different image files for different locales.

I cannot seem to do this using the new XCAssets functionality in Xcode 5. Is there a way to do this within the xcassets structure? Or do I have to import the images as separate files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've also looked for this, and after some time looking around it seems that is not possible for the moment using the xcassets, although it may change in the future... or not

Apple currently recommends that the launch image should simulate the app first screen but without content.

[Apple launch images guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/LaunchImages.html)

Comment: Yes, it's disappointing that Apple made this feature not complete. What you would suggest as workaround? In my case I deal with multi-resolution images (noted in `contents.json` for different devices), and I want somehow "easily" integrate localization of these images.

Comment: My workaround for this was just to drag the images into the Xcode project as assets (Just like you used to before xcassets came along) they can then be localized as with any other file.

Comment: Same workaround as @Sammio2, but best is to follow Apples' guidelines and use a very basic splashscreen, text-free

Answer (score 0):

Yes seems not possible with `xcassets` for now as per Macistador answer.

[image: Apple Document]